Power automate fails to run macro
Getting the below exception when trying to invoke a macro as part of the flow from power automate. There are total 5 macros being invoked. 4 of them work successfully but the 5th one fails with error. Invoking the macro from the excel directly has no issue. It is only when calling from flow in power automate
Error:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.: Microsoft.PowerPlatform.PowerAutomate.Desktop.Actions.SDK.ActionException: Failed to run macro. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot run the macro ''Inventory Forecast - AJ.xlsm'!UnpivotData()'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.Excel.Common.Extensions.ExcelHelper.InvokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object[] methodArgs)
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.Excel.Actions.ExcelActions.RunMacro(Variant excelInstance, Variant macro)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.Excel.Actions.ExcelActions.RunMacro(Variant excelInstance, Variant macro)
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.Excel.Actions.RunExcelMacro.Execute(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Engine.Execution.ActionRunner.Run(IActionStatement statement, Dictionary`2 inputArguments, Dictionary`2 outputArguments)

Already tried updating macro settings
